# um observer dentro de uma função observable não esta alimentando variável

Tags: javascript, angular

o que estou fazendo de errado? a variavel test nao esta sendo alimentada, sempre undefined

o result.data esta ok, a api esta funcionando e a consulta tbm, o problema eh a variavel test que sempre esta undefined

Angular+Apollo-graphql

```js
getUser(data: String): Observable<any> {
      let test: any
      this.apollo.query({ query: gql`${data}` }).subscribe(result => {
         test = result.data
      })
      console.log(test)//<< sempre retorna undefined
      return test
   }
```

Comment: **o que estou fazendo de errado?** É só olhar a sequência que o JavaScript é executado e saber o que é `assíncrono`!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você está registrando no console o valor da variável `test` antes que a resposta da API seja recebida.

O código que está dentro da função que você forneceu para o método `subscribe` só será executado quando uma resposta for recebida  por parte da API, mas o código que está fora desta função (mesmo que abaixo) continuará executando em sequência.

Resumindo: sua chamada a `console.log(test)` acontece antes que a sua atribuição `test = result.data`.

Você pode achar útil este link da MDN sobre programação assíncrona: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts.